# Python optparse: parse.error()---->TypeError: error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

Tags: python, typeerror, parse-error, optparse, msg

I am having trouble running this Trace Route module on the new Python 3.4.3. On the previous versions of python I was able to run the module yet now I am unable to. I keep receiving this Traceback error when I try calling the `parser.error()` function of optparse.

```
TypeError: error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'*
```

Here is a snippet of my code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage="%prog [options] hostname")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--port", dest="port",
                      help="Port to use for socket connection [default:%default]",
                      default=33434, metavar="PORT")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--max-hops", dest="max_hops",
                      help="Max hops before giving up [default: %default]",
                      default=30, metavar="MAXHOPS")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) != 1:
        parser.error()
    else:
        dest_name = args[0]

    sys.exit(main(dest_name=dest_name,
        port=int(options.port),
        max_hops=int(options.max_hops)))
```

The error keeps occuring at the "if" statement

```
if len(args) != 1:
    parser.error()
```

I then tried this

```
if len(args) != 1:
    parser.error("Incorrect number of arguments")
```

When I tried to run the module this time i received this error instead

```
  Usage: TraceRoute.py [options] hostname 
  TraceRoute.py: error: Incorrect number of arguments
```

I would love some feedback on how to fix this code in order to prevent this error and also more information on how to properly use the optparse library in python 3.4.3

Comment: [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html) is deprecated since Python 3.2. You should consider switching to `argparse`.

Comment: You are correct about how to fix your first issue -- so nice job.  As for your second issue, what are the options you're passing when you get that?

Comment: From what research I had been doing to correct my problem, it seemed with the new version of python that the optparse library got deprecated and that I would have to use the argparse library instead. I am still new to using parsing when coding especially in python.